# Loop that puts words into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

Loop in java that puts words into an ArrayList then a second loop that prints the string in the opposite order. I'm new to java and teaching myself via youtube and other websites, so if you have a good resource a link would be fantastic!

Comment: Just learn about loops and ArrayLists, and you'll be able to do it ;)

Comment: We don't do offsite resources here.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some basic tutorial directly at oracle. The ones for loops is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) .

Utilizing google you will find a lot of java turorials.